# plot numeric vector with names as x ticks

Tags: r, plot

I have a numeric vector and wish to plot each value on y-axis by their name on the x-axis.

Example:

```
quantity <- c(3,5,2)
names(quantity) <- c("apples","bananas", "pears")
plot(quantity)
```

Each value is plotted with it's index number along the x-axis ie. 1,2,3.  How can I get it to show ("apples","bananas", "pears")?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use function `axis()` to add labels. Argument `xaxt="n"` inside `plot()` will make plot without x axis labels (numbers).

```
plot(quantity,xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=1:3,labels=names(quantity))
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you look for `barplot`?

```
barplot(quantity)
```

Answer (score 4):

And another option using `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)
barchart(quantity)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem so I found this question, but once I looked at the answers and saw you could use names(named.vector) to get the names from the named.vector. Then I tried this and it worked.

`plot(x = quantity, y = names(quantity))`

I feel this is cleaner and simpler than a lot of the answers on this question. Even the one that was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `barplot` or `ggplot2` and have a graph of the following

```
quantity <- c(3, 5, 2)
names(quantity) <- c("apples", "banans", "pears")
barplot(quantity, main="Fruit Names vs. Quantity", xlab = "Names", ylab="Quantity", col=c("blue", "red", "yellow"))
legend("topright", legend=c("apples", "banas", "pears"), fill=c("blue", "red", "yellow"))
```

[image]